# I'm doing iOS build on the flutter, but an error appears. No such module 'GoogleUtilities'

Tags: android, ios, swift, flutter, android-studio

I'm doing iOS build on the flutter, but an error appears.
`No such module 'GoogleUtilities'`

Help Me

[image]

I was expecting a successful iOS build.

Answer (score 0):

Try this steps.

Make sure that you open `xcworkspace` instead of `xcodeproj.` `xcworkspace` - contains information about pods.

1. `flutter clean`
2. `flutter pub get`
3. `pod install` inside ios folder
4. Try to build